# Font in my mail sending program is not changing

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, email

**The Scenario:** I have a mail sending program in vb.net with backend Access database. When I created the default mail subject in Access database in Arial font format.

**The Issue:** After receiving the mail the mail subject is changed to Times New Roman.  I tried to change the database fonts to Arial, but it didn't resolve the issue.

**The Question:** How do I change the subject to Arial?

Comment: What client are you using to view the received email?

Comment: Also, you would have to apply a css rule to affect the font on the email. Having the font set in access wouldn't do anything.